# Block network access to local development server

Tags: security, xampp

I want a purely offline server for development of a wordpress theme.

I have installed XAMPP for Windows and started getting interested in security.  At the most basic level you add passwords for certain things, but what I really want to do is to stop ALL access to or from the internet for this server.  I want it to be purely local.

I use Comodo firewall.

Is it already going to allow access from local networks and the internet? I so, how do I change it? Do I want to change something in XAMPP's settings, or define a firewall rule?

Comment: Could just host the server on localhost but it wouldn't be accessible to the internal network. Alternatively you could use a private IP address, i.e. 10.0.0.x or 192.168.1.x, which would only be accessible in the local network.

Comment: right click on the firewall icon, firewall, block all.

Comment: @ekaj I think XAMPP uses already uses localhost. Which means I'm safe?

Comment: @Offler If it's a question of blocking it through the firewall, I'd probably be better asking in the Comodo forum.  I don't want to block all internet access (I still want to read superuser.com, for example) but I just don't want the offline development server accessing the internet/LAN.

Comment: If this makes things clearer, I access the server by going to 'localhost' in a browser.

Comment: I am not familiar with how XAMPP is set up, but you can run ipconfig and get your internal and external IP addresses and try both of those from another computer. If you can access the computer via the internal address you should be fine. It should not be possible to access it from the external address.

Comment: @ekaj Thank you for that tip. I will test it when I next go to work (where I connect my computer to a network).

Comment: Do you want the server to be accessible from your local network or not?

Comment: @terdon No, I don't. My local network is not a safe place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked how to configure my software firewall over on the [Comodo forums](https://forums.comodo.com/firewall-help-cis/block-network-access-to-local-development-server-t93523.0.html;msg673636#msg673636), and was given this answer:

Create an Application firewall rule for httpd.exe, something like:

```
Application Name - {your path to}\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Action - Allow
Protocol - TCP
Direction - In
Source Address - 127.0.0.1
Destination Address - Any
Source Port - Any
Destination Port - Any

Application Name - {your path to}\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Action - Block and Log
Protocol -  IP
Direction - In
Source Address - Any
Destination Address - Any
IP Details - Any
```

Comment: FYI: If using Mac OSX, you can just open: `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Firewall Options...`, then block all incoming connections to **httpd**.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to restrict a server to the local subnet only is to give it no gateway or default route.  Without the gateway, it won't be able to reach any other network.

However, I would still recommend a firewall and taking reasonable security precautions.  After all, you never know when one of the internet enabled computers on your network could get compromised and provide a "jumping off" point to your server.

Comment: Thank you @YLearn.  I am on the Comodo forum finding out how to make the right rules for my software firewall.  Regarding "Simplest way to restrict a server to the local subnet only is to give it no gateway or default route." - how would I do that?  I searched but it provided just more things that I don't understand. I don't know much about networking.

Comment: Often a server has an statically configured IP address and the gateway is set in the same place.  In this case, you would make sure the gateway field was blank.  You don't mention the version of Windows, but if you do a web search for "how do I change my IP in windows <version>" or I stumbled on this guide that may help: http://www.wikihow.com/Change-your-IP-Address-(Windows)